# Correct Power Supply Unit?

Tags: desktop, power-supply

Okay, so a while ago my Viotek V-1200 power supply unit went out. It makes this electrical buzzing noise when I go to power it on, and I don't have the ability to fix it so I'm looking for a new one. The problem is that I'm not sure what PSU to buy. My confusion comes from the amount of wattage my computer would need.

**SPECS:**

- Motherboard: MSI 990FXA-GD65
- CPU: AMD Phenom II x6 1070T
- Memory: x4 DDR3 4GB
- Video Card: Nvidia Geoforce GTX 550 Ti
- Storage: SATA 7.2K RPM (Barracuda 7200.12)
- Optical Drives: x1 DVD-RW/DVD+RW Drive & x1 DVD-ROM Drive
- USB Ports: 4x USB 2.0 & 2x USB 3.0

I used a power supply calculator (https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator) and its telling me that the recommended PSU wattage is about 461W, and is recommending an EVGA 650 BQ or EVGA 600 B1. These both cost less than $100, but I'm not sure if the price really means anything in this situation. My broken Viotek is 1200W. The jump from 1200 to anywhere below 800 worries me that my desktop won't have enough power. I may be wrong, but that's why I'm asking here.

Any help or PSU recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quite frankly, I'd be more worried about the quality of the PSU. You never needed 1200 W, but I definitely cannot recommend anything from Viotek. From what I've found they are substandard, and usually don't have enough amperage on the 12 V rail, which is what almost everything uses. Stick with something manufatured by one of the trusted manufacturers, like Seasonic, Superflower or check that they are manufactured with quality parts. It's worth the extra cost, wheras a silly amount of headroom isn't.

Comment: @Alpha3031 Would EVGA be considered as a quality manufacturer? I see their name on a lot more than just power supply units.

Comment: That said, it would be good if you detail any other requirements you might have (quietness, modularity, etc), as currently there are many PSUs that could suit your needs.

Comment: It depends, as EVGA doesn't actually manufacture PSUs, they take platforms by manufacturers and slap their brand on. Genrally, the G2, P2 and T2 series, which I believe are made by Superflower, are good, as are the GS, made by Seasonic. the older B series are slightly poorer quality, but should still be fine if you don't overtax them.